# GRUB doesn't boot the default entry (Ubuntu) automatically, keyboard sends ^[[[E

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 dual booted with Windows 10 on Lenovo E41-15 laptop. Some keys of my laptop weren't working since past two months. But overnight, some miracle happened and all of the keys are working, not sparing a single one. The problem is, GRUB no longer boots the default entry automatically, and no countdown is shown. ( I had set grub_timeout to 3 sec). I have to select the OS manually every time. Also, the Ubuntu "Quiet Splash" page flickers when booting. (This wasn't the case earlier). Moreover, when the boot details are being shown, there are multiple occurrences of `^[[[E` (see the image link below). I suspect a keystroke being sent repeatedly, which is causing all the problem. I tried checking the same with `xinput test 11` command, but there are no such keystrokes. It seems the problem persists only during boot. ( Not very sure about this).
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my /etc/default/grub file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'


GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""


# Added to enable grub hiding
#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

[Image1 showing the unusual key strokes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL2kf.jpg)

[Image2 showing the unusual key strokes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Dmf.jpg)

Comment: Your `Esc`-key stucks?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. It works fine when I use it. Tested with `xinput test`. Gives `^[` as the keystroke. Is there any other way to check if it's stuck, or test the entire keyboard?